# JavaScript get element through parent

Tags: javascript, select, parent

```
...
<td id="mycell">
   <input type="text" name="year" onmouseout="do_something(this.value,...);" />
   <input type="text" name="month" onmouseout="do_something(this.value,...);" />
</td>
...
```

i need to get value of neighbouring input element when submitting function on other element.
Thing is there are 10 of them and i cannot use id, names are same as well.

So i need to somehow get parent `<td>` and then address its child e.g. i submit year then  `onmouseout="do_something(this.value, this.parent.td.month.value");"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a reference to one of the input elements, then:

```
var td = input.parentNode;
```

And you can then select all child input elements using:

```
var inputs = td.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

And to get a particular one:

```
var input0 = inputs[0];
```

and so on. To get an adjacent input, find the current input in the `inputs` collection, then grab the next or previous (if there is one) as required.

Answer (score 0):

use the .next and .previous selector:

```
$(this).previous('input').val();
$(this).next('input').val();
```